# what is the position of duration in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

I understand that duration complement comes after the verb in a sentence i.e "我学了两个月汉语了" ,but with sentences like "我们得一个小时到机场" does the duration complement still apply here or is it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

我们得(在)一个小时(內)到机场 = We have to get to the airport (in) an hour (within) = We have to get to the airport within an hour

"An hour"(一个小时) in this sentence is not a [duration complement] but a [time expectation/condition phrase].

- [Duration complement] is the length of time already passed
- [Time Expectation/ Condition] is the length of time you are expected to spend, or the time you need to spend (a condition), therefore, the rule of [verb before duration complement] is not broken here

我们一个小时到机场 (we one hour to arrive at the airport) is an incomplete sentence. We need a verb before the duration complement here, for example, 我们**花了**一个小时到机场 (we **spent** one hour to arrive at the airport)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ,is there a book where I can get more examples?